# Want label in cell to have 2 lines. How do I append the second line?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Currently I have a tableView that uses a UITableViewCell with with two labels that appends data from parse.com. I am wondering if there is a way to append text to the second line of the labels. So on each label there is a number and on the second line I want to have individual text.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {
                 for object in objects {
                    var votes:Int? = object["Vote1"] as? Int
                    var votes2:Int? = object["Vote2"] as? Int
                    var totalvotes:Int? = votes! + votes2!
                    var vote1percentage = (votes! * 100) / totalvotes!
                    var vote2percentage = (votes2! * 100) / totalvotes!
                    self.singlevoteresult1.append("\(votes!)" as! String)
                    self.singlevoteresult2.append("\(votes2!)" as! String)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

So I want to append vote1percentage and vote2percentage to the second line of the label singlevoteresult1 and singlevoteresult2.

Here is the rest of the relevant code from the View Controller:

```
class NewFeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate {

var singlevoteresult1 = [String]()
var singlevoteresult2 = [String]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("feedcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewFeedControllerCell
    imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
    myCell2.voteResult1Outlet.text = singlevoteresult1[indexPath.row]
    myCell2.voteResult2Outlet.text = singlevoteresult2[indexPath.row]

    return myCell2
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my UIViewControllerCell:

```
class NewFeedControllerCell: UITableViewCell, UIActionSheetDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var dualVoteResult1Outlet: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var dualVoteResult2Outlet: UILabel!
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the label 2-line either in Interface Builder or by modifying `.numberOfLines` and then you put \n in the text when you want it create the new line.

For example:

```
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

label.numberOfLines = 2

let labelText = "First line\nSecond line"
label.text = labelText
```

Comment: self.singlevoteresult1.append("\(votes!)" as! String) how would i incorporate \n in there to have vote1percentage on the second line?

Comment: thanks that worked!!!!! u da best, dont let anyone ever tell u otherwise. i'll accept ur answer in 5 minutes

Comment: If you are creating the string from parts yourself, just put "\n" in between the two parts.

Answer (score 0):

@MirekE 's answer is right!
When you want the result of vote1percentage on the second line, you can make the code like: 
    String str = "I have\nvote1percentage"

If you want the second line different font color or other style, it can use NSAttributedString to set exactly style.